# How to fill a huge TableLayout without causing timeout ARNs?

Tags: android, multithreading, tablelayout, android-anr-dialog

I have a TableLayout with some hundreds of tablerows.

I'm filling it with a thread, which notifies to a handler when a row is created, and the handler adds the row in the UI thread. But the problem is that in some cases some users are reporting ARN due to:

> Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send key event because the
>   focused window has not finished processing all of the input events
>   that were previously delivered to it. Outbound queue length: 0. Wait
>   queue length: 1.)

The Android OS handles creating a ANR when it detects the UI/Main thread has been blocking for 5 seconds.

I thought using AsyncTask but is going to be deprecated in Android 11.

This is my thread:

```
private class PopulateTableThread extends Thread {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Player> players;

    public PopulateTableThread(Context context, ArrayList<Player> players) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.players = players;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i=0; i<players.size(); i++) {
            TableRow row = new TableRow(context);
            row.setLayoutParams(rowParams);
            row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_row_not_selected);

            String strings[] = {players.get(i).getName(),
                    "" + players.get(i).getTeam().getName(),
                    "" + players.get(i).getPositionInString(context),
                    "" + players.get(i).getYearsOfContractFormatted(),
                    "" + players.get(i).getValue() + " M€",
                    "" + players.get(i).getSalary() + " M€",
                    "" + players.get(i).getAge(),
                    "" + players.get(i).getBaseLevel()};

            for (int j = 0; j < strings.length; j++) {
                TextView text = new TextView(context);
                text.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_cell_background);

                if (j == 0) {
                    text.setLayoutParams(nameParams);
                    text.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                    text.setPadding((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.spacing_small), 0,  (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.spacing_small), 0);
                    text.setMaxLines(1);
                    text.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
                }else if (j == 1) {
                    text.setLayoutParams(teamNameParams);
                    text.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                    text.setPadding((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.spacing_small), 0,  (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.spacing_small), 0);
                    text.setMaxLines(1);
                    text.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
                } else if (j == 2 || j == 3) {
                    text.setLayoutParams(positionAndContractParams);
                    text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                } else if (j == 4) {
                    text.setLayoutParams(valueParams);
                    text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                } else if (j == 5) {
                    text.setLayoutParams(salaryParams);
                    text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                } else if (j == 6 || j == 7) {
                    text.setLayoutParams(ageAndLevelParams);
                    text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                }

                if (j == 3 && strings[3].split("/")[0].equals("1")) {
                    text.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_cell_background_danger);
                }

                text.setMinHeight((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.cell_height));
                text.setText(strings[j]);
                row.addView(text);
            }

            ProgressBar levelProgress = new ProgressBar(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.ProgressBar), null, 0);
            levelProgress.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_cell_background);
            levelProgress.setLayoutParams(levelBarParams);
            levelProgress.setMinimumHeight((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.cell_height));
            levelProgress.setProgress(players.get(i).getBaseLevel());
            levelProgress.setPadding((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.spacing_small), 0, (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.spacing_small), 0);
            row.addView(levelProgress);

            final int finalIndex = i;
            row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (searchProgressBar.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                        return;
                    }
                    SoundEffectsManager.getInstance().play(context, SoundEffectsManager.button);
                    displaySignDialog(players.get(finalIndex));
                }
            });

            Message message = new Message();
            message.what = HANDLER_ROW_CREATED;
            message.obj = row;
            updateTableHandler.sendMessage(message);
        }
        Message message = new Message();
        message.what = HANDLER_TABLE_FILLED;
        updateTableHandler.sendMessage(message);
    }
}
```

And this is the handler that it's updating the ui thread when the thread has created a new TableRow:

```
    updateTableHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what){
                case HANDLER_ROW_CREATED:
                    TableRow row = (TableRow) msg.obj;
                    tableLayout.addView(row);
                    break;
                case HANDLER_TABLE_FILLED:
                    tableLayout.setAlpha(1f);
                    searchProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
```

How can i avoid these ARN reports?

Trying to do David Wasser solution, but with same problem:

```
private class PopulateTableThread extends Thread {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Player> players;

    public PopulateTableThread(Context context, ArrayList<Player> players) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.players = players;
    }

    public void run() {
        Log.d("XXX_SeekerActivity","filling table with "+players.size()+" players");
        for (int i=0; i<players.size(); i++) {
            final String strings[] = {players.get(i).getName(),
                    "" + players.get(i).getTeam().getName(),
                    "" + players.get(i).getPositionInString(context),
                    "" + players.get(i).getYearsOfContractFormatted(),
                    "" + players.get(i).getValue() + " M€",
                    "" + players.get(i).getSalary() + " M€",
                    "" + players.get(i).getAge(),
                    "" + players.get(i).getBaseLevel()};

            final int finalI = i;
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    TableRow row = new TableRow(context);
                    row.setLayoutParams(rowParams);
                    row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_row_not_selected);

                    for (int j = 0; j < strings.length; j++) {
                        TextView text = new TextView(context);
                        text.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_cell_background);

                        if (j == 0) {
                            text.setLayoutParams(nameParams);
                            text.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                            text.setPadding((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.spacing_small), 0,  (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.spacing_small), 0);
                            text.setMaxLines(1);
                            text.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
                        }else if (j == 1) {
                            text.setLayoutParams(teamNameParams);
                            text.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                            text.setPadding((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.spacing_small), 0,  (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.spacing_small), 0);
                            text.setMaxLines(1);
                            text.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
                        } else if (j == 2 || j == 3) {
                            text.setLayoutParams(positionAndContractParams);
                            text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                        } else if (j == 4) {
                            text.setLayoutParams(valueParams);
                            text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                        } else if (j == 5) {
                            text.setLayoutParams(salaryParams);
                            text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                        } else if (j == 6 || j == 7) {
                            text.setLayoutParams(ageAndLevelParams);
                            text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                        }

                        if (j == 2) {
                            switch (players.get(finalI).getPosition()) {
                                case Player.PLAYER_POSITION_GOALKEEPER:
                                    text.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_cell_background_position_gk);
                                    break;
                                case Player.PLAYER_POSITION_DEFENDER:
                                    text.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_cell_background_position_def);
                                    break;
                                case Player.PLAYER_POSITION_MIDFIELDER:
                                    text.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_cell_background_position_mid);
                                    break;
                                case Player.PLAYER_POSITION_FORWARD:
                                    text.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_cell_background_position_fw);
                                    break;
                            }
                        }

                        if (j == 3 && strings[3].split("/")[0].equals("1")) {
                            text.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_cell_background_danger);
                        }

                        text.setMinHeight((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.cell_height));
                        text.setText(strings[j]);
                        row.addView(text);
                    }

                    ProgressBar levelProgress = new ProgressBar(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.ProgressBar), null, 0);
                    levelProgress.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_cell_background);
                    levelProgress.setLayoutParams(levelBarParams);
                    levelProgress.setMinimumHeight((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.cell_height));
                    levelProgress.setProgress(players.get(finalI).getBaseLevel());
                    levelProgress.setPadding((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.spacing_small), 0, (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.spacing_small), 0);
                    row.addView(levelProgress);

                    final int finalIndex = finalI;
                    row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            if (searchProgressBar.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                                return;
                            }
                            SoundEffectsManager.getInstance().play(context, SoundEffectsManager.button);
                            displaySignDialog(players.get(finalIndex));
                        }
                    });

                    row.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(final View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                            if (searchProgressBar.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                                return true;
                            }

                            switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                                    delayColorizeHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            Util.getInstance().colorizeBackgroundCheckingApiLevel(view);
                                        }
                                    }, Util.WAIT_TIME_BEFORE_TOUCH_COLORIZE);
                                    break;
                                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                                    delayColorizeHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
                                    Util.getInstance().clearBackgroundColorFilter(view);
                                    break;
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                    });

                    tableLayout.addView(row);
                }
            });
        }
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tableLayout.setAlpha(1f);
                searchProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't create and manipulate UI elements (`TableRow`, `TextView`, etc.) on a background thread. All this stuff needs to be done on the main (UI) thread directly. You are probably creating object locks on parts of the UI framework that is blocking the main (UI) thread and causing your ANR.

Have your background thread loop over your players and get the data for each one. Then it can post a `Runnable` to the main (UI) thread (once for each player) with the player data and in the `Runnable` (which will run on the main (UI) thread) you can create the UI elements and add them to your layout.

By doing this in a loop in a background thread, you won't block the UI thread.

Comment: Hi David, thank you, can you share a little sample of that runable? I think I'm not getting exactly what do you want to do in that runnable. I'm doing something similar with my handler. And I don't know how to post a runnable to the uithread from that thread

Comment: do you mean using runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    }
});
 and creating the tablerow and adding it in that run method?

Comment: but check my code, I'm creating textviews and other views in the thread, more or less the 80% of the code is that, retrieving the data is only a few lines. Do you mean putting that 80% of the code in a main ui thread with runOnUiThread? How can that solve the problem? I can't understand it. If it's in the ui thread will block the ui too

Comment: Yes, you must run all that code on the UI thread! It won't block the UI thread if you break it up into little snippets (as I've suggested, one player at a time).

Comment: I tryed it, but the problem is the same, it takes a lot of time to paint those hundreds of rows, even I think that it's taking more time. Please can you check my question and tell me if I'm doing something wron with your proposal? I edited my question and added your proposal source code changed

Comment: I'm doing as you told me, one player at a time, with ruinonuithread trick. But with same or even worst result blocking the UI when adding the 600-700 rows

Comment: OK, you can't create that many UI elements. Your approach is wrong. You should use a ListView or RecyclerView or GridView. In this case you won't need to create more than a handful of actual table rows and these will be reused as the user scrolls through the list. Read up on how to do that.

Comment: In any case, the code you wrote is NOT what I suggested. I suggested that you call `runOnUiThread()` once for **each** player. You've not done that. You've called it only once and packed all the code to create all the UI elements in a single call! This will, of course, take too long and cause an ANR.

Comment: If you want to try to fix this, call `runOnUiThread()` once for **each** player, inside the loop. Inside the `run()` method you want to just create a single row.

Comment: check my code, it's calling runonuithread once per player, there is a for which iterates each player, and for each is calling runonuithread once

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was probably tired when I wrote that. Sorry. Just refer to my comment about using `ListView` or something similar. You obviously can't create that many UI elements.